# Can I use 2 POST requests on click of one button using html, mysql and NODE.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mysql, node.js

I want to save form details to MYSQL database and also mail the form details to admin using nodemailer.
So far I am able to send data to admin and save data to MySql database individually but what I want it to do is to save and send form details simultaneously.

```
    app.post('/send',function(req,res){

        var type_lea=req.body.lev_type.value
        res.write('type "' + req.body.lev_type.value+'".\n');
      let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
          host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
          port: 465,
          secure: true,
          auth: {
              user: 'marcus1313@gmail.com',
              pass: 'Password'
          }
      });

    app.post('/submit',function(req,res){

      var employ_id=req.body.emp_id;
    var reason=req.body.leave_reason;
    var sql = "INSERT INTO leave_det (Emp_id,Reason) VALUES                                         
    ('"+req.body.emp_id+"','"+         req.body.leave_reason+"',)";
        conn.query(sql, function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 record inserted");

        });
```

in this html code I am able to call only one post request but I want to call them both at the same time.

```
    <form action="/send" name="mail"  class="loyal" method="post" >
   </form>
```

Comment: Generally You should have a single route `app.post('/send',function(req,res){` and in that you have to do the logic of saving into DB and once it done you can trigger the mail in success response of DB saving

Comment: Just use one route "/send" and use your /submit code there?

Comment: write the two block of codes in one post request

Comment: And you need to be careful with this SQL-Query. 
Its not safe against SQL-Injections

Comment: ArayniMax please elaborate this topic you just stated it seems like some serious matter.

Comment: Thanks I will be editing the code and try the solution guys and I hope it will work Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: _“ArayniMax please elaborate this topic you just stated it seems like some serious matter.”_ - it’s a well-known, age-old matter … so _you_ please go make the effort and inform yourself.

Comment: I'll do thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: by the way the solution you guys gave worked thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this method may be it will help you

```
var app = express()

function otherPath(req, res, next) {
    return res.send('ok')
}

function home(req, res, next) {
    req.url = '/other/path'
  /* Uncomment the next line if you want to change the method 
    req.method = 'POST'
  */
    return app._router.handle(req, res, next)
}
app.get('/other/path', otherPath)
app.get('/', home)
```

Comment: so here you are calling one request at the end of the former request i.e 2nd req. will be called when the 1st request is handled. Nice thanks i will try this method too.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send your POST request to one single endpoint. But this should not be an issue here as you may call your mailing code within the same function where you store the data to the database.

As the call to the SMTP server will take some time, I would move the mailing task completely out of the loop here. Just write to the database and do the mailing in a seperate background processing job.

Please also check your SQL statement carefully for risks of SQL injection.

Comment: Thank You your help is greatly appreciated